# My MacBook Pro Shocks Me When I Connect It To A Three-Prong Charger

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, charging

There are already many questions about how to solve a problem where touching a MacBook Pro while it is charging gives one an electric shock. In most of cases, connecting a three-prong extension to the charger and using it seems to solve the problem (since that allows the MacBook Pro to be properly "grounded" or something).

My case, however, is quite the opposite. I receive moderately severe electric shocks when I touch my MacBook Pro (13", late 2011) when it is connected and charging using the three-prong extension. What I can't understand is that I still receive shocks even if the switch on the wall socket that the charger is plugged into is switched **OFF**.

When I switch to using a two-prong connector for my charger, the electric shocks go away but I still feel a slight tingling sensation when touching the edge of my MacBook Pro. If I switch to using a two-prong, third-party MacBook Pro charger I got off Amazon, I still feel the slight tingling sensation, but I don't get shocked very badly, either.

I've tried using multiple three-prong extensions and multiple two-prong extensions, plugged my charger into multiple sockets around my house, and even plugged my faulty charger into another MacBook Pro—and I've observed the same behavior I described above every time.

I'm really confused and I can't find much help on this online. Does anybody have any idea what could be happening and how I can fix it?

(I happen to live in a country where the standard voltage is 240V, if that matters.)

Comment: I see two possibilities [vague because your evidence doesn't quite add up to a single conclusion] - both of which need a professional to check - 1) the capacitors in the old charger are failing, lessening the power-smoothing on the rectifier, &/or 2) the house has swapped live & neutral, exacerbating the first issue. Potentially 3) the earth in your sockets isn't grounding properly. I don't see any of these being a DIY fix, unless your first test is a simple socket tester from a DIY store; but it if checks out less than perfect, then you need a pro.

Comment: Hm... would any of those possibilities explain why when using my three-prong charger, I receive electric shocks even when the switch on the wall socket is turned off? I don't know much about electricity and I don't know whether to think that's happening because of my charger or my power supply.

Comment: The socket being mis-wired could explain that. I can't think of anything else that would. 240v 3-pin switched sockets should switch the live, leaving the neutral & earth still connected. If it's wired wrongly...

Comment: I would definitely recommend taking your laptop and 3-prong charger to someone else's house and test it there. If the problem goes away there, you will want to call an electrician.

Comment: If you get a shock from a powerpoint which is switched off you have a **SERIOUS and potentially DANGEROUS** wiring problem which should be investigated by a licensed electrician or your electrical authority. Wiring regulations differ between countries and in Australia/NZ this should not be possible, but there a number of instances of faulty wiring and this could be indicative of an faulty neutral/earth bonding.